# How to display a date filter consisting of custom date selector and buttons

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, filter

I am building an iOS application which contains a list of videos, these videos can be filtered by date. I am looking for a better way to display these filters on Mobile, with such a limited screen space.

The User can select a custom start date and a custom end date via dropdown menus. Alternatively they can click a button for quick selection, *30 days ago*, *1 year ago* and three others.

Here's how my app looks now:

[image: Application filter page]

Comment: Apply kind of gets lost from all the other options. Have you considered making "apply" an actual button so it stands out and is clear about what actions to take?

Comment: I've always wondered about the usefulness of date filters (except in special cases). Usually I'm looking for relatively newer or older stuff, but not stuff within a particular date range. (Was that puppy video posted last week? or the week before that?) So I find date sort more useful than date filters.

Answer (score 1):

When apps give the option to enter a custom date range, it's usually presented alongside the other options. Then if the user taps it, an area would expand and the user would be able to set the start and end date. So your menu options would be:

- Last 30 days
- Last 6 months
- Last year
- Year to date
- Custom date range

However, I'd really consider whether your video app needs functionality this advanced. For example, YouTube doesn't have the ability to search by a custom date range—they just have:

- Last hour
- Today
- This week
- This month
- This year

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into three filters.

Two would define the date range (both triggering a date selector):

- **Start date**
- **End date**

And I would also support these two fields with a button **[Or select a period]** using the UIPickerView with options:

- Last 30 days
- Last month
- Last 6 months
- Last year
- Year to date

Selecting a period by the User would then update start & end date values based on preselection.

By the way, I understand that last month means 1st to last day of the previous month. It is not 100% clear, though, I think that you would avoid ambiguity by changing it to **Previous month** as opposed to **Last 30 days**, same about **Previous year** versus **Year to date**, so it would be instead:

- Last 30 days
- Previous month
- Last 6 months
- Previous year
- Year to date

Or even grouping it not by how much time is contained within a specific range but what type of range it is (and providing some more consistency by changing Year to date to Last 12 months):

- Last 30 days
- Last 6 months
- Last 12 months
- Previous month
- Previous year.